# How to submit a form having dropdown values using ajax in flask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, ajax, flask

I am trying to submit a form with having a dropdown list using ajax and jquery in the flask. I was able to submit any simple form, but the form with a dropdown list is not getting submitted via ajax. What may be the possible error? or in which step I am doing the mistake?

I am getting  **Method Not Allowed,
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.** error.

Please find the code below:-

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('sample_selector_dashboard.html')

@app.route('/sample_selector', methods=['POST', 'GET']) 
def sample_selector():
  print(request.method)
  sel_lbl = request.form.get('lbl')          
  sel_country = request.form.get('cntry')
  print(sel_lbl, "-", sel_country)

  return render_template('sample_selector_dashboard.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

**sample_selector_dashboard.html**

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet"
integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Our CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ 
  url_for('static',filename='styles/styles.css') }}">

  <title>Flask Sample Selector</title>
  </head>

 <body>

 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row flex-nowrap">
  <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
        <form id="sample-submit" method="post">
          <div class="nav-item dropdown" id="select-class-dropdown">
            <h4>Select Class</h4>
            <select id="class_s" name="class_s" class="form-select form-control"
              aria-label="Default select example">
              <option value="speed_limit_010">speed_limit_010</option>
              <option value="speed_limit_020">speed_limit_020</option>
              <option value="speed_limit_030">speed_limit_030</option>
              <option value="speed_limit_040">speed_limit_040</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="nav-item dropdown" id="select-label-dropdown">
            <h4>Select Label</h4>
            <select id="label_s" name="label_s" class="form-select form-control"
              aria-label="Default select example">
              <option value="speed_limit_010">speed_limit_010_l</option>
              <option value="speed_limit_020">speed_limit_020_l</option>
              <option value="speed_limit_030">speed_limit_030_l</option>
              <option value="speed_limit_040">speed_limit_040_l</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="nav-item dropdown">
            <h4>Select Cluster</h4>
            <select id="cluster" name="cluster" class="form-select form-control"
              aria-label="Default select example">
              <option value="asi">ASIA</option>
              <option value="europe">EUROPE</option>
              <option value="africa">AFRICA</option>
              <option value="usa">USA</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-item dropdown" id="select-country-dropdown">
            <h4> Select Country</h4>
            <select id="country" name="country" class="form-select form-control"
              aria-label="Default select example">
              <option value="india">IN</option>
              <option value="germany">DE</option>
              <option value="austria">AT</option>
              <option value="pakistan">PK</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" id="get_images" name="get_images" class="btn btn-info" value="Get_Images">Get Images
          </button>
        </form>


        <button type="button" id="good" onclick="get_selected_samples_list_on_good_button_click()"
          class="btn btn-success">Good</button>


      </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

</body>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<!--  Our JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', 
filename='scripts/index.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

** index.js **

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('form').on('submit', function(event) {

    $.ajax({
        data : {
            cls : $('#class_s').val(),
            lbl : $('#label_s').val(),
            cluster : $('#cluster').val(),
            cntry : $('#country').val()
        },
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/sample_selector'
    })
    .done(function(data) {

        if (data.error) {
            alert("Erroe")
        }
        else {
            alert("Success")
        }

    });

    event.preventDefault();

});

});
```

Comment: I don't see index.js linked in your html file.

Comment: @Musa sorry, there was a mistake in posting the question. Now I have edited it. Even with the javascript linked, same issue.